# Would a question on designing a compression algorithm belong on CSTheory?

Tags: discussion, migration, specific-question

Some time ago, I asked [Compression of domain names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801753/compression-of-domain-names) on StackOverflow.

I've been wondering whether it wouldn't be more suited to CSTheory, but when I suggested to the SO mods that it be migrated the response I received was:

> I'm not sure it would belong there. Try asking on their meta if it should be moved. The site mods should contact us and ask for it.

Grateful for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only accept *research-level* questions and only in *theoretical* computer science. Please check the site's FAQ for further explanation regarding our scope.

Many SO users are not familiar with this and what this means and make migration suggestions when the question is outside our scope. A very high percentage of questions migrated from SO to cstheory are rejected (closed as off-topic) and naturally SO moderators are reluctant to migrate any question here.

For general CS questions you can try CS.SE.